# Tiny icon on visual studio completion list meaning

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Visual studio 2019's completion list]

Hello, what is the meaning of the tiny heart-shaped icon in completion lists for Intellisense?

Comment: I use C# yes i do

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2019

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not really about programming, and is not likely to ever help anyone else, ever.

Comment: This is the reason for putting the visual-studio tag. "Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is called a [Signal Icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2019#signal-icons).

The heart icon in particular is for the `internal` access modifier.